# Month function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Provided a date, say '2011-08-06'.

Is it `Month(Date) = 08` or `Month(Date) = '08'`?

Comment: Very much depends on what you're trying to do and what specific database product you're using (please [edit] and add an appropriate tag and explanation). Date functions are highly vendor specific.

Comment: `Month` returns `Number`, `8` in your case

Comment: It is equal to `8`, the integer.

Comment: Sorry but- your question is a two liner and writing that into an SQL - console would be easier than asking!

Comment: the two of them are correct (even if Damien_The_Unbeliever say it )  it depend of what you have to do if it's a simple query it can be number 1 if you use it in a report (let say ireport) it can be the second one

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx, return type int.

Answer (score 2):

Its in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx)

> Returns an **integer** that represents the month of the specified date.

`MONTH('2011-08-06')` returns `8`.